# What hibernate property name should use

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to configure connection with database in hibernate.cfg.xml.
But don't know what name of property I should use:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class
```

or whithout *hibernate*

```
connection.driver_class
```

In a [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-firstclass) used whithout *hibernate*, but in the next [chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html) already with.

What name is right and why?

Comment: Always refer to the DOCS: [3.4. Optional configuration properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)

Comment: And here is the one you need: [3.3. JDBC connections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `hibernate.properties` you should use

`hibernate.connection.driver_class`

The main reason that, if you look at the code where `hibernate.properties` is read — [Environment](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.java?av=f#206), you can see, that properties merged with other properties as is. So a `hibernate` prefix is need to Hibernate can recognize his properties.

In the `hibernate.cfg.xml` you can use

`connection.driver_class` or `hibernate.connection.driver_class`

This code snippet is from `LoadedConfig` class that gets properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
private void addConfigurationValue(String propertyName, String value) {
    value = trim( value );
    configurationValues.put( propertyName, value );

    if ( !propertyName.startsWith( "hibernate." ) ) {
        configurationValues.put( "hibernate." + propertyName, value );
    }
}
```

Properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml` are used as is and with the `hibernate.` prefix. Two properties are added for every property without the `hibernate.` prefix.

**Summary**

It is not much sense with this strange behaviour. It is just code. It the first case properties are added as is, in the second it is corrected.

**The best approach**

Always use `hibernate.connection.driver_class`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!